# Using Ace Editor with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ace-editor

I'm building the design of a small online IDE with Twitter Bootstrap, but i'm failing to achieve the proper layout due to Ace's height problem.

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
                <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <a class="brand" href=""><img alt="" src=""></a>

                    <ul class="nav pull-right">
                        bla bla bla
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span3">
                <p>This is a sidebar</p>
            </div>
            <div class="span9">
                <div id="editor">asdasdasddas
                asd
                das
                das
                das
                das</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

This is a simple Twitter bootstrap navbar and the container, with two grid columns: one for the sidebar, another for the editor. However, the Ace Editor does not use it's parent height, no matter what i do. How can i create something just like the actual Ace Editor kitchen sink, but using Twitter Bootstrap in a responsive manner (like Cloud9, for example)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ace uses size of the element to which it is attached
you can do either of following

- make span9 `position:relative` make editor `position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0`
- call ace.edit on span9
- set editor size with js see https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/ace.js#L96